# A palavra "malaco" existe no português europeu?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, termos

Alguns brasileiros devem saber o motivo desta pergunta. Recentemente houve uma denúncia por parte de um jogador de futebol brasileiro de que um colega de profissão português teria proferido ofensas racistas direcionadas a ele, fato esse negado pelo jogador português, que afirma ter chamado o jogador brasileiro de "malaco" e que o jogador brasileiro teria se confundido graças às diferenças de pronúncia que ambos os sotaques têm.

Minha pergunta então é simples, caros amigos portugueses: essa palavra existe? Qual o seu significado?

Comment: Um momentinho. O brasileiro ouviu "macaco"? Macaco é racista. Mas, malaco está no Priberam. Por favor, faça a pesquisa antes de fazer a pergunta. https://dicionario.priberam.org/malaco Isso não tem nada que ver com "diferença de pronuncia". Tem a ver com palavras diferentes dos dois lados da moeda.

Comment: Seria difícil acreditar que um jogador como Rafael Ramos seja racista na medida em que jogou no Corintios muito tempo.....

Comment: @lambie não vou fazer juízo de valor sobre o que o rapaz disse ou não disse, esse fórum nem é para isso, fiz a pesquisa e vi que a palavra realmente existe mas não no Brasil seu uso é completamente desconhecido e como jamais tive a oportunidade de conhecer Portugal tampouco posso dizer se é realmente usado por lá, o que no fundo é o que mais me interessa tirar dessa pergunta

Comment: Calma. Só estou dizendo que o Rafael Ramos veio do Santa Claro (nos Açores) e muitos no time são de descendência africana. Se ve nas fotos do clube. Não seria a primeira vez que brasileiros e portugueses não se entendem. Em todo caso, eu vi que supostamente ele disse: Mano, caralho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A palavra existe… mas pelos vistos, só no Brasil. Eu em Portugal nunca ouvi, e todos os exemplos de uso que encontrei são de brasileiros. De sete dicionários que consultei, só a encontrei no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/malaco), que basicamente diz que significa ’homem estúpido’ ou ’malandro’, e que é regionalismo, mas não diz que regiões:

> **malaco**
> (origem obscura, talvez de *malandro*)
> *substantivo masculino*
>
> 1. [Regionalismo, Depreciativo] Homem estúpido.
> 2. [Regionalismo, Depreciativo] Indivíduo que procura viver de atividades ilícitas ou à custa do trabalho alheio = MALANDRO

Entretanto, o [dicionário informal](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/malaco/1/) tem 14 definições, todas elas de usuários brasileiros. A grande maioria deles diz que *malaco* é mais ou menos o mesmo que ’malandro, esperto, manhoso’, nunca ’estúpido’. A maioria dos usuários são de São Paulo. As definições variam um bocado. Duas põem a ênfase na maneira de vestir: “bermudas estampadas com moleton com capuz” ou “camisa da Adidas”. Aparentemente, *malaco* é uma gíria, e o significado exato pode variar algo de comunidade para comunidade.

Os exemplos de uso no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/malaco) ― [“o vírus é malaco”](http://serpoeta.blogspot.com/2020/08/rondo-do-destino.html) (2020), [“O Buraco é malaco e supimpa!”](http://persivo.blogspot.com/2020/07/quatro-anos-de-glorias-sem-comemoracoes.html) (2020) e [“impeachment malaco”](https://altamiroborges.blogspot.com/2018/04/a-bocalidade-triunfante-no-pos-golpe.html) (2018) ― também são de autores brasileiros.

No Google Books encontram-se vários exemplos. Mais uma vez, dos que vi, são todos de autores brasileiros. O significado parece andar sempre à volta de ’malandro’. O exemplo mais antigo que encontrei, sem fazer uma busca exaustiva, é de 1984:

> […] o cara é malandro, é malaco […]
> [*I Ciclo do Pensamento Curitibano*, Fundação Cultural de Curitiba, 1984](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1ihwAAAAMAAJ&q=malandro%20%C3%A9%20malaco&dq=malandro%20%C3%A9%20malaco&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjexoathez3AhUmyoUKHVmOCEYQ6AF6BAgDEAI)

Comment: muitíssimo obrigado pela contribuição, o que mas me interessava dessa pergunta era se essa palavra era usada em PT, como nunca estive ai não podia ter certeza. aqui no BR, pelo menos em São Paulo que é onde vivo, em mais de 26 anos nunca escutei esta palavra

Comment: @FabricioG, já me aconteceu a mim também, no meu caso ao fim de cinquenta e tal anos, encontrar uma palavra usada aqui em certos meios e que eu nunca tinha ouvido antes. O que significa que *malaco* pode ser usado aqui em certos meios sem eu saber. Por descargo de consciência fiz uma busca restringindo a Portugal e encontrei uma [referência ao termo "malaco"](https://alemguadiana.blogs.sapo.pt/88121.html) (anterior à polémica atual, no Alentejo), mas nem diz o que significa. Existe também como sobrenome, que eu também nunca tinha ouvido.

Comment: Faz tempo que não ouço *malaco*. Mal me lembro do significado, mas me lembro de ser BEM ofensiva.

Comment: Estou com o Jacinto, nunca ouvi "malaco" em Portugal.